# Disable or Turn IIS off

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7

I'm trying to learn how to host WCF Services. I know how to stop IIS, by right clicking and telling it to stop. But when the computer reboots it will turn back on.

I don't know what is the best option. I want to try to host my service in Windows services now instead of IIS. (I will need to turn it back on later.) I'm afraid there will be a conflict if I try to host both at the same time. Besides doesn't that waste resources?

Also if I'm not using IIS on a daily basis it should be turned off from what i understand.

I'm using Windows 7 and IIS 7.

I need to use the WCF Service on IIS and the Windows Service I  only when i need it. I don't need them to start automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: Create Windows Services with Startup Type as Manual

Comment: Thanks! I did not see this. But it would not have been very helpful because I'm new to this and I wouldn't have known what you meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer: it is found at http://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/disabling-the-microsoft-internet-information-server-iis.

Basically I went to Run on the start menu. I typed "services.msc" without the quotes. I got a list of services in the Services dialog box. I found IIS Admin Service. I right clicked it and switched to Manual so i can turn it off and on when i got ready.